# Eclipse server configuration messed up terribly

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ide

In Eclipse, while adding a new server, I accidently added a 'project' as a resource to the server. Now, in all my servers, this project (which I've already deleted from hard disk) appears as a resource, and I can't get rid of it. Here's a screenshot, shown when I try to Run the project and it asks me to select the server:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to reinstall Eclipse, switch workspaces, but I can't get rid of it. Because of this, I'm getting a lot of errors whenever I try to run even a sample app. How do I get rid of this 'resource' and just start over?

Comment: I have never used the eclipse server configuration and I don not know how it works, but if you switched to a clean workspace and a new eclipse installation, without success, I would assume that the server configuration is written to a configuration file of your server?

Comment: @Thomas Its found in multiple servers, not just one. All my servers have this 'test' resource added.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the test and do remove as you have shown in the screenshot or delete the server and define new server..[image]